# VS2012 std library xutility unreadable implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, std

I'm trying to understand xutility from the C++ Standard Library that ships with VS2012. As has been the case for all versions of the standard library that have ever shipped with VS none of it is pretty. But there are two declarations in particular that have me completely stumped. Namely the globally declared structs _Get_unchecked_type and _Is_checked_helper.

The implementation of _Get_unchecked_type looks something like this.

```cpp
// file <xutility>

        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Get_unchecked_type
template<class _Ty>
    struct _Get_unchecked_type
        _GET_TYPE_OR_DEFAULT(_Unchecked_type,
            _Ty);
```

```cpp
// file <xtr1common>

#define _GET_TYPE_OR_DEFAULT(TYPE, DEFAULT) \
    { \
    template<class _Uty> \
        static auto _Fn(int) \
            -> typename _Uty::TYPE; \
 \
    template<class _Uty> \
        static auto _Fn(_Wrap_int) \
            -> DEFAULT; \
 \
    typedef decltype(_Fn<_Ty>(0)) type; \
    }
```

So. _Get_unchecked_type is a struct, the entire body of which is defined by a macro _GET_TYPE_OR_DEFAULT defined in xtr1common.

The first argument to _GET_TYPE_OR_DEFAULT is _Unchecked_type which does not appear to be meaningfully defined anywhere. Mousing over _Unchecked_type the popup tells you that it is 'typedef <error-type> _Unchecked_type' which doesn't make any sense since '<error-type>' is not a valid type. Right clicking _Unchecked_type and selecting 'Go To Definition' takes you to the definition of _Array_const_iterator::_Unchecked_type which also cannot be right since struct _Get_unchecked_type is defined at global scope.

So the first question is, what is _Unchecked_type, where is it defined, and how are you expected to work that out?

Moving on to the definition of _GET_TYPE_OR_DEFAULT. This macro declares two static member function templates overloads called _Fn. For the life of me I can't find the definitions of these. What do these do, where are they defined, and how are you supposed to work that out either?

The definition of _Is_checked_helper is similarly obtuse.

Can someone help me understand what these do and how they work please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xutility` is part of the implementation, and is not at all intended to be readable. It may use Undefined internal compiler behavior. `_Unchecked_type` is a name that is reserved for the compiler, and may be predefined like `int` for all we know.

Anyway, this defines member `type` via overload selection on `_Fn`. There are 2 methods named `Fn`, one taking `int` and returning `Ty::TYPE` and the other taking `_Wrap_int` and returning the second macro argument `DEFAULT`. The first conversion is better, but assumes that `Ty::TYPE` exists.

Therefore, `_Get_unchecked_type<A>::type` is `A::_Unchecked_type` if that exists, and just `A` otherwise.

Comment: Many thanks. With your help I think I understand now. But it does irk me though that library writers don't seem to feel any obligation to make their code readable, especially for libraries like the Standard Library that are designed to be extended. And I don't really see how xutility can be considered an implementation detail when it contains much of the core iterator declarations that you would need to understand if you wished to create a new Standard Library compliant container, or even just a new iterator specialization.

Comment: I think much of the problem here lies with C++ itself though, in that for template code it provides no effective way to separate interface from implementation. I had hoped that C++11 would bring some progress in this area but if anything it seems to be getting worse, which is odd since in the area of non-template code the degree of separation C++ supports between interface and implementation code is as good as any other language out there.

Comment: @Neutrino: C++ is of course the only mainstream language which has templates. Java and .Net defined generics specifically to avoid the issues C++ has with templates, and the result is that generics can cause boxing. Plus, they can't do template meta-programming. As for extension, you do not need `xutility` at all.  In fact, you can now use STL-compatible containers in for-loops without including any header.